# Usando delphi e proxy socket4, conectar em site e obter html

Tags: delphi, socket, proxy

Preciso acessar um site utilizando proxy socket4 e obter o html. Importante não usar componentes visuais.

Já tentei utilizar o TclientSocket, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Utilizando proxy socket4, preciso conectar em um site e retornar o html da página. A solução precisa ser realizada em delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de você não dê muitos detalhes sobre o que vc realmente deseja.

"Utilizando proxy socket4, preciso conectar em um site e retornar o html da página. A solução precisa ser realizada em delphi. " Não foi suficiente rs

**Tem essa situação aqui**

https://forum.scriptbrasil.com.br/topic/178004-resolvido%c2%a0twebbrowser-proxy-list/

Caso não queria componentes visuais crie dinamicamente.

Se passar mais informações facilita bastante...